# Como generar un parametro de fechas en excel?

Tags: excel, formulas

tengo un parametro de fechas acomodadas por niveles, tomando en cuenta la fecha de hoy,

```
30 dias antes de hoy = fase1, 
45 dias antes de hoy =fase 2, 
60 dias antes de hoy=fase 3, 
90 dias antes de hoy = fase 4 
y mas de 90 dias apartir de hoy=fase 5.
```

Entonces tengo un listado de clientes con su fecha de expiración, por lo tanto quiero saber en que fase cae cada una de dichas entidades

tambien se que se puede hacer manual, pero esa no es la intencion ya que ahorita es con una base pequeña pero la intencion es automatizar este proceso.

[image: parametros entre fechas en excel]

Comment: muchas gracias me fue muy util !!! y me sirvio mucho :D, mi seguiente pregunta es.... ya con esta formula puedo hacer que un boton dandole clic me genere la consulta ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agrega una columna a la derecha de tu fecha de por cada cliente con esta formula [SIFECHA](https://exceltotal.com/la-funcion-sifecha/)

```
=SIFECHA(H2,$H$1,"D")
```

Ajustando a tus filas y columnas correspondientes

Con lo anterior calcularemos cuantos dias han pasado desde la fecha indicada por `H1` que en tu caso puede ponerse como formula `=HOY()`

Lo siguiente se puede hacer varias formas, una que me acomoda es usar la funcion SI. Asi que agregaremos una columna a la derecha del numero de dias de cada fecha

y podemos usar un formula como

```
=SI(I2<$A$2,$B$2,SI(I2<$A$3,$B$3,SI(I2<$A$4,$B$4,SI(I2<$A$5,$B$5,$B$6))))
```

Donde el rango `A2:B6` es :

```
A   B
30  L1
45  L2
60  L3
90  L4
91  L5
```

Y en este caso I2 es el numero de dias que hay de diferencia entre las fechas.

Que nos daria de resultado

```
| G        | H         | I | J | 
            08/02/2017      
Cliente 1   31/01/2017  8   L1
Cliente 2   26/01/2017  13  L1
Cliente 3   21/01/2017  18  L1
Cliente 4   16/01/2017  23  L1
Cliente 5   11/01/2017  28  L1
Cliente 6   06/01/2017  33  L2
Cliente 7   01/01/2017  38  L2
Cliente 8   27/12/2016  43  L2
Cliente 9   22/12/2016  48  L3
Cliente 10  17/12/2016  53  L3
Cliente 11  12/12/2016  58  L3
Cliente 12  07/12/2016  63  L4
Cliente 13  02/12/2016  68  L4
Cliente 14  27/11/2016  73  L4
Cliente 15  22/11/2016  78  L4
Cliente 16  17/11/2016  83  L4
Cliente 17  12/11/2016  88  L4
Cliente 18  07/11/2016  93  L5
Cliente 19  02/11/2016  98  L5
Cliente 20  28/10/2016  103 L5
Cliente 21  23/10/2016  108 L5
```

Comment: muchas gracias me fue muy util !!! y me sirvio mucho :D, mi seguiente pregunta es.... ya con esta formula puedo hacer que un boton dandole clic me genere la consulta ?

Answer (score 1):

**Fórmula:**

```
=BUSCARV(  [celda con la fecha]  ,  [tabla de fechas ascendentes]  ,2,VERDADERO)
```

Vayamos al caso concreto. Si se tiene la lista de fechas en `A1:B7`, con las fechas en orden ascendente, es decir en el orden inverso al que lo estabas presentando:

```
|   |    A     |   B    |
|---|----------|--------|
| 1 | Fecha    | Fase   |
| 2 | 0        | fase 5 |
| 3 | 10/11/16 | fase 4 |
| 4 | 10/12/16 | fase 3 |
| 5 | 25/12/16 | fase 2 |
| 6 | 9/01/17  | fase 1 |
| 7 | 8/02/17  | fase 0 |
```

- la primera fecha está en 0 para incluir a todas las fechas.
- El resto de las fechas se calculan como `=HOY()-90`, `=HOY()-60`, `=HOY()-45`, `=HOY()-30`, y `=HOY()`.
- Viendo que la respuesta aceptada fue usando días laborales, las fechas se calcularían con `=DIA.LAB(HOY(),-90)`, `=DIA.LAB(HOY(),-60)`, `=DIA.LAB(HOY(),-45)`, `=DIA.LAB(HOY(),-30)`, y `=HOY()`.

Y si se tiene la tabla a generar en `D1:E999`

```
|   |       D       |                 E                  |
|---|---------------|------------------------------------|
| 1 | Fecha Cliente | Fase                               |
| 2 | 8/02/17       | =BUSCARV(D2,$A$2:$B$7,2,VERDADERO) |
| 3 | 15/01/17      | =BUSCARV(D3,$A$2:$B$7,2,VERDADERO) |
| 4 | 30/12/16      | =BUSCARV(D4,$A$2:$B$7,2,VERDADERO) |
| 5 | 10/12/16      | =BUSCARV(D5,$A$2:$B$7,2,VERDADERO) |
| 6 | 15/11/16      | =BUSCARV(D6,$A$2:$B$7,2,VERDADERO) |
| 7 | ...           | ...                                |
```

La fórmula se aplica como se ve arriba.

**Lo importante** de esto es que el último parámetro de `BUSCARV()` en `VERDADERO` hace que retorne el valor de la última fila que no sea mayor al valor buscado.

**Resultado:**

[image: Captura que muestra los valores bien calculados]

Comment: muchas gracias me fue muy util !!! y me sirvio mucho :D, mi seguiente pregunta es.... ya con esta formula puedo hacer que un boton dandole clic me genere la consulta ?

Comment: Antes que nada, esa sería una nueva pregunta. La idea del sitio es hacer 1 sola pregunta por publicación. Sin embargo, te adelanto lo que te repreguntaría: ¿qué consulta? Si tenés la tabla con fechas de cliente, sólo hay que copiar la fórmula de `E2` y copiarla al resto de la columna E.

Comment: perdona la molestia soy nuevo pero no se como contactarte por este medio ..... hay alguna otra forma de contactarte ? es para una consulta..... ya que nadie me ha podido responder.. te agradeceria tu ayuda. saludos.

Comment: @EmmanuelHM Click en [Formular nueva pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) y podrás escribir lo que quieras consultar.

Answer (score 1):

Puede servirte así:

**B** se calcula con:
=DIAS.LAB(A2,HOY())

**C** se calcula con:
=SI(B2<31,"L1",SI(B2<46,"L2",SI(B2<61,"L3",SI(B2<91,"L4","L5"))))

[image: Tabla con resultados:]

--
Se aplica a: Excel 2016 Excel 2013 Excel 2010 Excel 2007 Excel 2016 para Mac Excel para Mac 2011 Excel Online Excel para iPad Excel para iPhone Excel para tabletas Android Excel Starter Excel Mobile Excel para teléfonos Android

La función de días laborales se describe [acá](https://support.office.com/es-es/article/DIAS-LAB-funci%C3%B3n-DIAS-LAB-48e717bf-a7a3-495f-969e-5005e3eb18e7).

Comment: muchas gracias me fue muy util !!! y me sirvio mucho :D, mi seguiente pregunta es.... ya con esta formula puedo hacer que un boton dandole clic me genere la consulta ?