# Evaluar fechas con función SI en Excel

Tags: excel, formulas

A ver si me pueden apoyar con la función `SI` evaluando fechas dentro de un rango para indicarme a que fase corresponde.

**Parámetros:**

```
FASE1 = del 31 de enero del 2017 para atrás
FASE2 = se encuentre entre 1 Febrero 2017 a 30 Junio 2017
FASE3 = se encentre entre 1 Julio 2017 a 31 Diciembre 2017
FASE4 = todo lo que tenga fecha del 1 Enero 2018 en adelante
```

**Resultado Buscado:**

En base a la fecha de la `Columna A` me indique en la `Columna B` a que fase corresponde.

```
Columna A    Columna B
30/04/2015   FASE1     
31/12/2015   FASE1 
31/03/2016   FASE1
30/09/2015   FASE1
31/12/2014   FASE1
05/02/2019   FASE4
31/08/2017   FASE3
20/04/2017   FASE2
```

**Ejemplo de fórmula esperada:**

```
=SI(A1<31/01/2017,"FASE1",SI(A1<01/02/2017,"FASE2",SI(A1>30/06/2017,"FASE2",SI(A1>01/07/2018,"FASE3",SI(A1<31/12/2017"FASE4",”FASE5”))))
```

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Como generar un parametro de fechas en excel?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48490/como-generar-un-parametro-de-fechas-en-excel)

Comment: No es duplicado la otra lo hace por numero de dias... totales, esta es por rango de fechas...   @Mariano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considerando que las fechas comenzarían en la columna A1:

```
=SI(A1 <= FECHA(2017;1;31); "Fase 1"; SI(A1...))
```

Comment: Super mil gracias estimado !!!